# Как сохранять значение таблицы после перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript

Есть таблица с `id="table_t"` и ячейка к примеру с `id="new"`. Пользователь вводит через prompt(""); значение которое сохраняется в переменную. Потом через скрипт переменная присваивается ячейке("new"), но после перезагрузки страницы ячейка восстанавливает прежнее значение... что делать? ЕСТЬ ВОЗМОЖНОСТЬ СОХРАНЕНИЯ ДАННЫХ НА СЕРВЕРЕ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нет возможности запоминать данные на сервере, то можно хранить их в localStorage (HTML5).

Сохранение:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('z', window.prompt("?"));
```

Извлечение:

```
window.alert(window.localStorage.getItem('z'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Помимо localStorage можно использовать cookie.

Для чтения и записи cookie используется свойство document.cookie. Однако, оно представляет собой не объект, а строку в специальном формате, для удобной манипуляций с которой нужны дополнительные функции.

## Получение cookie

Следующая функция getCookie(name) возвращает cookie с именем name:

```
// возвращает cookie с именем name, если есть, если нет, то undefined
function getCookie(name) {
   var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
   "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + 
   "=([^;]*)"
));
 return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
}
```

Обрати внимание, что значение может быть любым. Если оно содержит символы, нарушающие форматирование, например, пробелы или ;, то оно кодируется при помощи encodeURIComponent. Функция getCookie автоматически раскодирует его.

## Создание cookie

```
function setCookie(name, value, options) {
  options = options || {};

  var expires = options.expires;

  if (typeof expires == "number" && expires) {
   var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + expires * 1000);
   expires = options.expires = d;
  }
  if (expires && expires.toUTCString) {
   options.expires = expires.toUTCString();
  }

  value = encodeURIComponent(value);

  var updatedCookie = name + "=" + value;

  for (var propName in options) {
    updatedCookie += "; " + propName;
    var propValue = options[propName];
   if (propValue !== true) {
      updatedCookie += "=" + propValue;
   }
  }

  document.cookie = updatedCookie;
}
```

#### Аргументы данной функции

**name**
название cookie

**value**
значение cookie (строка)

**options**
Объект с дополнительными свойствами для установки cookie:

**expires**
Время истечения cookie. Интерпретируется по-разному, в зависимости от типа:

- *Число* – количество секунд до истечения.
- *Объект типа Date* - дата истечения.

Также стоит упомянуть, что:

- Если expires в прошлом, то cookie будет удалено.
- Если expires отсутствует или 0, то cookie будет установлено как сессионное и исчезнет при закрытии браузера.

**path**
Путь для cookie.

**domain**
Домен для cookie.

**secure**
Если true, то пересылать cookie только по защищенному соединению.

## Удаление cookie

Здесь всё просто – удаляем вызовом setCookie с датой в прошлом.

```
function deleteCookie(name) {
  setCookie(name, "", {
    expires: -1
   })
}
```